# How to fail gracefully in IE instead of seeing SCRIPT5009 if a variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, error-handling

```
if (!variable) ui.notify('functionality not available due to...');
```

When doing this simple check in IE we get SCRIPT5009: 'variable' is undefined, where it is exactly what we are trying to check but not fail so disgracefully. How to make this graceful fail come true?

Comment: I thought there were lots of similar questions on this topic but this one was missing. Thanks for answers. Always good to know the other trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next code can help you:

```
if (typeof variable === "undefined") console.log("undefined");
else console.log("defined");
```

Comment: This one is more classic than the other, but it doesn't account for the fact that it will only work in debug mode, as you must check for typeof console in advance as well before calling console.log(). Sorry I can only choose one for answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can replace `console.log()` with you own code ( _ui.notify()_ ...) For example: `if (typeof variable === "undefined") ui.notify('functionality not available due to...');`. This does not matter. More over this code must work with any variable: global, local or defined in closure. Operator `typeof` in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#typeof

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
if (!window['variable']) ui.notify('functionality not available due to...');
```

assuming that `variable` is global